# Bottom overflowed by pixels only in LANDSCAPE

Tags: android-studio, flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I want to make a simple intro route when the app opens. It has a background image some text and a button. It runs ok in vertical position but in landscape the text disappears but the button remains visible.
I tried multiple widgets to make it adaptive but not working because the background image disappears or also the text.
[image]
[image]

```
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class Intro extends StatefulWidget {
  

  @override
  _IntroState createState() => _IntroState();
}
class _IntroState extends State<Intro> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        body: Container(
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        image: DecorationImage(
          image: AssetImage("images/phone.png"),
          fit: BoxFit.cover,
        ),
      ),
      child: Stack(
        children: <Widget>[
          Container(
            color: Colors.black54,
            child: Column(
              children: <Widget>[
                const SizedBox(height: kToolbarHeight + 250),
                Expanded(
                  child: Column(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Text(
                        """TITLE OF THE APP""",
                        style: TextStyle(
                          color: Colors.white70,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                          fontSize: 30.0,
                        ),
                      ),
                      const SizedBox(height: 20.0),
                      Text(
                        """SUBTITLE""",
                        style: TextStyle(
                          color: Colors.white70,
                          fontSize: 18.0,
                        ),
                        textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
                const SizedBox(height: 10.0),
                Center(
                  child: Row(
                    children: <Widget>[],
                  ),
                ),
                FlatButton.icon(
                  color: Colors.black12,
                  textColor: Colors.white70,
                  shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
                  ),
                  icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_forward_ios_rounded),
                  label: Text("SIMPLE BUTTON"),
                  onPressed: () {
                    Navigator.pushNamed(context, 'HomePage');
                  },
                ),
                const SizedBox(height: 150.0),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    ));
  }
}
```

Comment: change stack into column and use expanded to container

Comment: thank you for your. but it does not work. it wipes everything